# template pattern and simplejdbtemplate

Tags: spring, design-patterns

I've used [SimpleJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html) and am comfortable with it. I also grasp (or think I do) the concept of the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Yet I'm having some trouble putting these 2 together. How does SimpleJdbcTemplate implement this pattern exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's JDBC Template (and JMS Template and lots of other templates) have NOTHING to do with Template Method.

Spring's templates aim to reduce boilerplate codes by encapsulating them inside methods, and let users provide meaningful logic by callbacks, strategies impl etc.

Template Method is a specific design pattern that a super class define the overall flow and let subclass hook its own pieces of logic by implementing some specific methods.